# Where did Holborn come from?

Tags: tamora-pierce, tortall-universe

In Tamora Pierce's book [Mastiff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375814701), it mentions that Beka Cooper was engaged to a fellow Dog named Holborn, who she met somewhere around the Bread Riots in 247 HE.

I looked in the previous book, Bloodhound, and I can't find a mention of Holborn anywhere in and around the time the Bread Riots are mentioned. Is Holborn actually in that book? I know that Beka has a different lover in Bloodhound, but do we get to see Holborn at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember reading anything about him, cannot find any reference to him when scanning the book, and the [Tamora Pierce Wikia](http://tamorapierce.wikia.com/wiki/Mastiff) refers to him as

> a five-year Lower City Day Watch Dog named Holborn, whom we never meet.

I would say no, we never meet Holburn within the text of [Bloodhound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375838171).

Comment: Okay, so I am not crazy, then. That's good. The reference to meeting him during the riots made me think that maybe we saw a peek at him when she met Dale, but I read that scene over and over and didn't see it. :)